# How to replace part of href= value from a javascript variable similer to phps str_replace(..)?

Tags: javascript

i got javascript variable(code2) that holds the following data:

```
<div class="pages"><center><a class="selected" href="/Episodes-1234_power1" title="power album page 1" >1</a><a class="normal" href="/Episodes-1234_power2" title="power album page 2"> 2</a>
```

and i want to change it to this:

```
<div class="pages"><center><a class="selected" href="./doit.php?title=<?php echo $_GET['title'];?>&Num=/Episodes-1234_power1" title="power album page 1" >1</a><a class="normal" href="./doit.php?title=<?php echo $_GET['title'];?>&Num=/Episodes-1234_power2" title="power album page 2"> 2</a>
```

I have doen similer thing in php like this example :

```
$code2=str_replace('href="', 'href="./doit.php?title='.$title.'&Num=', $code1);
echo $code2;
```

I tried to do same thing in javascript but my following code doesnt work! could you guys help me fix it? Thanks

```
<script>
.....
.....
alert ('' + code2);

 //document.write(code2);
var myString = code2;
var myString2 = myString.replace(href=, 'href="./doit.php?title=<?php echo $_GET['title'];?>&Num=');

document.write (myString2);
</script>
```

Comment: Your JS has a syntax error: missing quotation marks around `href=`. Or possibly you intended it as a regex, in which case it should be `/href=/` (Also your replacement string should probably have a closing `"` just before the closing `'`.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript `replace` method basically just like the PHP one, and make use of its support for regular expressions to match against the href value in a general sense. Basically like this:

```
var theSecondString = theFirstString.replace(/href=".+"/, theReplacementString);
```

Using `/href=".+"/` means it will look for the href 'key', as well as anything that follows in double quotes, and then it replaces all of that with your replacement string.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tadRP/) that shows it in action.

**edit:** The regex should instead have been `/href="/g` to include also the original href component; the same principle applies in the general sense though, of couse, here is an [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tadRP/4/)

Comment: Thanks all for reply. kieran i run your script in action it only replaces the second href only . It even doesnt display da first href after clicking ! Furthermore, how i can do the replacement in run time without any clicking ? just when the page loads ? Note: we assume that the two paging urls never posted so we want to replace first then output to the user! how i can do that ?

Comment: Hey, to replace all of them you would add the 'g' flag to the regular expression, which forces it to match all rather than just the first it finds (read more [at mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) if you want). You can just move the replacement logic into your main script, or call the function with an 'onload' event rather than use a button press, I just put that in there so it was easy to see the difference. Here is [the updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tadRP/1/)

Comment: thanks kieran but why it removed the /Episodes-1234_power1 and /Episodes-1234_power2 from the href ? is there a way to keep those parts ? since those are required to move to the next page ?

Comment: No worries, glad we got there in the end.

Answer (score -1):

I like to make strings like that into actual dom elements then use methods to manipulate from there:

```
var div = ​docu​ment.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = code2

var a = div.querySelectorAll('a')[0];
a.href = "./doit.php?title=<?php echo $_GET['title'];?>&Num=";

document.body.appendChild(div)
```